# yield inside with block in python function

Tags: python, generator, yield, with-statement

I don't understand what's happening when the following function is called:

```
def doSmth(inFile):
    print inFile
    with open(inFile,'r') as trainSet:
        for instLine in trainSet:

            # do smth
            yield instLine
```

why when the last line with yield is removed there's an error
that the file doesn't exist (it really doesn't exist). Whereas, when I have the line
, there's no error.
Another question, why in the second case, **print inFile** has no effect while it has in the first case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you aren't actually iterating over the generator:

You have something similar to this in your code:

```
doSmth() # simply creates generator without advancing it
```

without the `for x in doSmth()`